# How to replace % symbol from a string?

Tags: php, str-replace

```
foreach($data_features as $feature){
    echo $feature['feature'].'<br>'; //string contains % symbol
    $featur =  str_replace("%", "'", $feature['feature']);
    $featur =  str_replace("!", '"',  $feature['feature']);                     
    echo '<li>'.$featur.'</li>'; // string still contains % symbol.
}
```

Here $feature['feature'] is a string that contains % symbol and I want to replace the % symbol using str_replace however % symbol is still present in the output.

Comment: @RST how is that related to my question.

Comment: https://eval.in/651654  .It's working. So i am unable to understand your problem?

Comment: I found out my mistake had to put in a variable and then apply str_replace operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may helps you:-

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    $data_features =  Array ( 
    '0' => Array ( 
            'id' => 1, 
            'product_id' => 1, 
            'feature' => 'Customisation-With an open OS, you%re in control.', 
            'time_added' => '2016-09-28 15:33:28',
            'product_asin' => 'B014UUQUAO' 
        ), 
    '1' => Array ( 
            'id' => 2, 
            'product_id' => 1, 
            'feature' => 'Enhanced Expirences- We believe core experiences like audio, email, and calling can be better. That%s we%re re.', 
            'time_added' => '2016-09-28 15:33:28', 
            'product_asin' => 'B014UUQUAO'
        ),
    '2' => Array ( 
            'id' => 3, 
            'product_id' => 1, 
            'feature' => 'Privacy & Securitye.', 
            'time_added' => '2016-09-28 15:33:28', 
            'product_asin' => 'B014UUQUAO' 
        ) 
 );

echo "<pre/>";print_r($data_features);
foreach($data_features as $feature){
    $featur = $feature['feature'];
    $find = array('/%/', '/!/');
    $replace = array("'", '"');
    $result = preg_replace($find, $replace, $feature['feature']);

    echo '<li>'.$result.'</li>';
}
?>
```

output:-https://eval.in/651753

Note:-

Instead of multiple `str_replace()`, Single `preg_replace()` with `$find`  and `$replace` array is good idea.

In near future if some more replecement needed then only change in `$find`  and `$replace` will needed.

Comment: Glad to help you.:):)

Answer (score 1):

I found out my mistake had to put in a variable and then apply str_replace operation.Don't know the reason somehow.

```
foreach($data_features as $feature){
    $featur = $feature['feature'];
    $featur =  str_replace("%", "'", $featur);
    $featur =  str_replace("!", '"', $featur);                      
    echo '<li>'.$featur.'</li>';
}
```

Comment: @Anant  Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [product_id] => 1 [feature] => Customisation-With an open OS, you%re in control. [time_added] => 2016-09-28 15:33:28 [product_asin] => B014UUQUAO ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [product_id] => 1 [feature] => Enhanced Expirences- We believe core experiences like audio, email, and calling can be better. That%s  we%re re. [time_added] => 2016-09-28 15:33:28 [product_asin] => B014UUQUAO ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [product_id] => 1 [feature] => Privacy & Securitye. [time_added] => 2016-09-28 15:33:28 [product_asin] => B014UUQUAO ) )